# Reload page by JavaScript continues once after clicking a link

Tags: javascript, jquery, reload

I want to refresh my order page to update it with new orders:

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        window.setTimeout(function(){
            location.reload();
        }, 2000);
    });
</script>
```

It works fine. However, when I leave the page, e.g. by clicking a link, the page is being refreshed once more. It seems like the `location.reload()` is being cached/remembered in advance or so.

I simply want the reload to stop once I leave the page.

How can I prevent this behaviour?

Comment: When you reload the page your script will get executed again, so the setTimeoute will run again after 2 seconds.
if you want to update you page use AJAX.

Comment: I understand the thought, but I feel it shouldn't be necessary to create extra load on the server.